# How to persist svelte store state across route change?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper, svelte-3, svelte-store

I have a svelte store object `user` that is set to another object `consumer` whenever the `consumer` object changes:

```
$: $user = consumer;
```

I can see that `user` is being updated however when I change the route by either button click with href or `window.location.replace()` the store appears to be reset.

I couldn't find anything in the docs about this. How can I persist the store across route change? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (probably my own) future reference:

I worked out the issue. I am using sapper - I should have been using `goto()` as documented here: https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#goto_href_options